# Cellular data usage of Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I'm creating an app that will probably require a lot of cellular data use, which I want to limit as much as possible. (A lot of images)

Is there a way to check how much data is sent/recieved from Parse? 
For example:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "image")
query.whereKey("something", equalTo: "somethingelse")
var images = query.findObjects()
```

How much data will a requests such as that be if the images array contains several hundred PFObjects? Will it be 128kb * amount of images?

And lastly: I want to refresh this quite a few times, is there a way to limit this or do I have to download the array and compare it to the array I've previously saved locally from the last query?

Comment: Regarding your last question, you could always use Cloud Code which would get the array but only send parts of the array you want to the device (which would obviously help save data)

Comment: why not use `kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork` this will always try and load the data previously downloaded into cache first